# Disable UIButton within IBAction Closure - Swift 4

Tags: uibutton, swift4, ibaction

When the user is playing my app, there are certain buttons that I do not want them to accidentally press. So, I would like to grey out and disable them when the app is in `gameMode = 1`. The following code disables the button when it is supposed to but then does not enable again it when I need it to (when it is in `gameMode = 0`). Also the button does not grey out.

```
@IBAction func menuButton(_ sender: UIButton) {  

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")

    if gameMode == 0 {

        sender.isEnabled = true
        self.present(myVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

    } else if gameMode == 1 {
        sender.isEnabled = false

    }
}
```

Comment: when does the error appear on typing or on running the app abd when the button is pressed?

Comment: I solved that problem with `sender.isEnabled = false`, but now  I can't get the logic to work properly and the button does not grey out. Please see updated question.

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to set `isEnabled` when `gameMode` changes, at the moment you're trying to do it when the button action is run.

Comment: You're right. But, how can I reference the `sender` object from within another function. I could reference IBOutlets objects in other functions and change `.isEnabled` to `true` or `false` that way. But I'm wondering if this is possible without IBOutlets (i.e. by just using the `sender` object). Avoiding IBOutlets will not reduce code much but it will reduce time spent making connections in Storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func menuButton(_ sender: UIButton) {  

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")

    if gameMode == 0 {

        sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.present(myVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

    } else if gameMode == 1 {
        sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    }
}
```

Comment: 2 ERRORS: **Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'isUserInteractionEnabled'**

Comment: 2 ERRORS: Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'isUserInteractionEnabled'

Comment: Create object of YourButton using IBoutlet and use it's object to do the task